# BinaryFormatter and Deserialization Complex objects

Tags: c#, binaryformatter

Can not deserialize following object graph. That Exception occurs when deserialize method called on BinaryFormmater:
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException :

```
The constructor to deserialize an object of type 'C' was not found.
```

There're two constructor on C. and I think the problem may be : While serialization Binaryformatter using the paramatered one and on deserialization process, it needs a parameterless one. Is there a hack / solution?
Objects :

```
  [Serializable]
    public class A
    {
        B b;
        C c;

        public int ID { get; set; }

        public A()
        {
        }

        public A(B b)
        {
            this.b = b;
        }

        public A(C c)
        {
            this.c = c;
        }
    }
    [Serializable]
    public class B
    {

    }
    [Serializable]
    public class C : Dictionary<int, A>
    {
        public C()
        {

        }

        public C(List<A> list)
        {
            list.ForEach(p => this.Add(p.ID, p));
        }
    }
```

// Serialization success

```
    byte[] result;
    using (var stream =new MemoryStream())
    {
        new BinaryFormatter ().Serialize (stream, source);
        stream.Flush ();
        result = stream.ToArray ();
    }
    return result;
```

// Deserialization fails

```
    object result = null;
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
    {
        result = new BinaryFormatter ().Deserialize (stream);
    }
    return result;
```

The calls are at the same environment, same thread, same method

```
        List<A> alist = new List<A>()
        {
            new A {ID = 1},
            new A {ID = 2}
        };

        C c = new C(alist);
        var fetched = Serialize (c); // success
        var obj = Deserialize(fetched); // failes
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I suspect you just need to provide a deserialization constructor to `C`, since dictionary implements `ISerializable`:

```
protected C(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctx) : base(info, ctx) {}
```

checked (passes):

```
 static void Main() {
     C c = new C();
     c.Add(123, new A { ID = 456});
     using(var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
         var ser = new BinaryFormatter();
         ser.Serialize(ms, c);
         ms.Position = 0;
         C clone = (C)ser.Deserialize(ms);
         Console.WriteLine(clone.Count); // writes 1
         Console.WriteLine(clone[123].ID); // writes 456
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your serialization will succeed when you implement class C as following:

```
[Serializable]
public class C : IDictionary<int,A>
{
    private Dictionary<int,A> _inner = new Dictionary<int,A>;

    // implement interface ...
}
```

The problem is the serialization of the Dictionary derived class.