# Deserialization from MemoryStream()

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, deserialization, memorystream

Lets say, I have a class with objects in it.

```
namespace Class_Serialization
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Data
    {
        public string Name = "Example1";
        public string place = "Torino";
        public DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

I am trying to serialize it using ISerialization interface

```
[Serializable]
public class SerializeThisClass : ISerializable
{
    public Data StreamThisData;

    public SerializeThisClass()
    {

    }

    public SerializeThisClass(Data _StreamThisData)
    {
        StreamThisData = _StreamThisData;
    }
    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.SerializationFormatter)]
    void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("Object Data", StreamThisData);
    }
}
```

Now, When I serialize with the code below

```
Data DataToSerialize = new Data();
BinaryFormatter DataToBinary = new BinaryFormatter();
SerializeThisClass serialize = new SerializeThisClass(DataToSerialize);
SerializeIn SerializeInMem = new SerializeIn();
DataToBinary.Serialize(SerializeInMem.StreamOfData, serialize);
ListOfStreams.Add(SerializeInMem);
```

It serializes normally, but when I try to deserialize it, it gives me error

```
BinaryFormatter BinaryToData = new BinaryFormatter();
foreach (SerializeIn x in ListOfStreams)
{
    x.StreamOfData.Position = 0;
    SerializeThisClass DeserializeData = (SerializeThisClass)BinaryToData.Deserialize(x.StreamOfData);
    MessageBox.Show("Name: " + DeserializeData.StreamThisData.Name + "\nPlace: " + DeserializeData.StreamThisData.place + "\nDateTime: " + DeserializeData.StreamThisData.time.ToString());
}
```

> Error: $exception{"The constructor to deserialize an object of type
>   'Class_Serialization.SerializeThisClass' was not found."}
>   System.Exception {System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException}

Comment: Try do it this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017274/c-sharp-binaryformatter-and-deserialization-complex-objects

Comment: Frankly, given that all you are doing is adding a single element, I'd be tempted to remove `ISerializable` and just let `BinaryFormatter` handle it automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are implementing `ISerializable`, you need a constructor of the signature:

```
protected YourType(SerializationInfo information, StreamingContext context) {}
```

which loads the data (basically, the reverse of `GetObjectData`). Presumably, with (untested):

```
StreamThisData = (Data)info.GetValue("Object Data", typeof(Data));
```

Comment: +1 Although I knew what was missing, damned if I could remember the explanation! lol

Comment: @JasimKhanAfridi Your `GetObjectData` is used when serializing, the constructor is used when deserializing.  As Marc says, it should simply do the reverse and pull values out of the container into your class.

Comment: @JasimKhanAfridi in all seriousness, you almost certainly don't need to actually implement ISerializable here. Just sayin'

Comment: @JasimKhanAfridi second what Marc almost all of the `ISerializable` implementations I've seen are written by new c# developers that don't understand how serialization attributes work yet.  You almost certainly don't need it here.  If stock serialization isn't doing it for you look  at `OnDeserializedAttribute` before implementing ISerializable.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the constructor:

```
protected SerializeThisClass(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182343(v=vs.80).aspx