How to update existing cache using HybridCache in .NET 9
I am trying to see if I can update a cached collection (in memory) using HybridCache.
When using MemoryCache, I can do something like this, this was an easy "hack" to update collection without removing it from memory:
var list1 = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };
IMemoryCache cache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());
cache.Set("Key", list1);

if (cache.TryGetValue<List<string>>("Key", out List<string>? result))
{
    result!.Add("d");
}

var list = cache.Get("Key");

EDIT: even if "by default, HybridCache uses MemoryCache", it doesn't work like the MemoryCache, using the reference types. There are some methods which are not implemented, such as TryGetValue, I just wanted to see if it was possible or there is an alternate way, obviously you can drop the key.

Did not know MemoryCache did this with reference types.. I have some code checking to do! Are you asking if this works with HybridCache? Have you tried it?

“In memory cached objects are stored within the same process space as the cache client process. When a cache client requests a cached object, the client receives a reference to the locally cached object rather than a copy.” - sounds to me this will not work with HybridCache - ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14278472/43846

@stuartd, Yeah, I have tried. There are no TryGetValue or Exists methods. Sometimes it's useful to update an existing collection without reloading the whole set. When I first found out, I thought it was a bug, but apparently, it's by design. So, we can take advantage of it! I just wanted to see if it was possible since "by default, HybridCache uses MemoryCache."

It might due to be in pre-release? I mean it might change in future. By the way, have you tired the SetAsync method?

I don't know the specific details of this behaviour in HybridCache from Microsoft, but can I suggest taking a look at FusionCache (shameless plug) as an alternative hybrid cache?
The behaviour you are looking for will work with FusionCache by default, unless you explicitly opt-in to using Auto-Clone.
FusionCache has been battle tested in production for years, has basically the same design as HybridCache but with more flexibility, more features, extra resiliency and is even already used by Microsoft itself (see here).
For a quick intro there's this On .NET episode.
Hope this helps.

My understanding is that the behavior you are experiencing is based on the assumption that HybridCache is primarily used in conjunction with IDistributedCache (L2).
You can find the explanation in the documentation:

In typical existing code that uses IDistributedCache, every retrieval of an object from the cache results in deserialization. This behavior means that each concurrent caller gets a separate instance of the object, which can't interact with other instances. The result is thread safety, as there's no risk of concurrent modifications to the same object instance.


Because much HybridCache usage will be adapted from existing IDistributedCache code, HybridCache preserves this behavior by default to avoid introducing concurrency bugs.

As suggested by @TinyWang, the alternate way would be to use the SetAsync method to reflect your change across all the cache levels:
var value = await cache.GetOrCreateAsync(
    "MyKey",
    _ => ValueTask.FromResult(new List<string> { "a", "b" }));

value.Add("c");

await cache.SetAsync("MyKey", value);

value = await cache.GetOrCreateAsync(
    "MyKey",
    _ => ValueTask.FromResult(new List<string> { "a", "b" }));

Debug.Assert(value.Count == 3);

