# serialize/deserialize a list of objects using BinaryFormatter

Tags: c#, object, serialization, deserialization, binaryformatter

I know there were already many discussions on that topic, like this one:

[BinaryFormatter and Deserialization Complex objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017274/binaryformatter-and-deserialization-complex-objects)

but this looks awfully complicated. What I'm looking for is an easier way to serialize and deserialize a generic List of objects into/from one file. This is what I've tried:

```
    public void SaveFile(string fileName)
    {
        List<object> objects = new List<object>();

        // Add all tree nodes
        objects.Add(treeView.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().ToList());

        // Add dictionary (Type: Dictionary<int, Tuple<List<string>, List<string>>>)
        objects.Add(dictionary);

        using(Stream file = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            bf.Serialize(file, objects);
        }
    }

    public void LoadFile(string fileName)
    {
        ClearAll();
        using(Stream file = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

            object obj = bf.Deserialize(file);

            // Error: ArgumentNullException in System.Core.dll
            TreeNode[] nodeList = (obj as IEnumerable<TreeNode>).ToArray();

            treeView.Nodes.AddRange(nodeList);

            dictionary = obj as Dictionary<int, Tuple<List<string>, List<string>>>;

        }
    }
```

The serialization works, but the deserialization fails with an ArgumentNullException. Does anyone know how to pull the dictionary and the tree nodes out and cast them back, may be with a different approach, but also nice and simple? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it seems 'obj' was indeed null, but in my bloody-beginner-view it wasn't. :-S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have serialized a list of objects where the first item is a list of nodes and the second a dictionary. So when deserializing, you will get the same objects back.

The result from deserializing will be a `List<object>`, where the first element is a `List<TreeNode>` and the second element a `Dictionary<int, Tuple<List<string>, List<string>>>`

Something like this:

```
public static void LoadFile(string fileName)
{
    ClearAll();
    using(Stream file = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open))
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

        object obj = bf.Deserialize(file);

        var objects  = obj as List<object>;
        //you may want to run some checks (objects is not null and contains 2 elements for example)
        var nodes = objects[0] as List<TreeNode>;
        var dictionary = objects[1] as Dictionary<int, Tuple<List<string>,List<string>>>;
        
        //use nodes and dictionary
    }
}
```

You can give it a try [on this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uPZ1HN).

Comment: Amazing, now it works flawless. Seems I should gain some knowledge about how formatters work. Thank you for the revision! By the way: Great tool!

Comment: Glad to help! (I really like dotnetfiddle)